# Как отличить местоимение, связывающее 2 части предложения от союза?

Tags: местоимения

Например: Весь вечер мы наблюдали за звездами, **которые** красиво мерцали на небе.
И еще: как отличить предлоги от частиц?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Местоимение в таком случае является членом предложения, а союз нет. В Вашем предложении слово "которые", связывающее две части сложного предложения, является местоимением (союзным словом), выполняющим в  придаточном предложении роль подлежащего. Союз же не является членом предложения, к нему нельзя поставить вопрос: "Я хочу, ЧТОБЫ ты прислал мне письмо".
 А теперь об отличии частиц от предлогов. Предлоги связывают слова между собой: "работать на компьютере". Без предлога "на" слова "работать компьютере" были бы бессмысленным набором слов. Частицы же придают слову или предложению какой-либо оттенок значения: вопросительный, отрицательный, утвердительный и т.д.

Comment: Местоимение связывающее части предложения называется союзным словом?

Comment: Все слова, используемые как союзы, но таковыми не являющиеся, называются союзными словами. Если это местоимение, значит мы имеем дело с местоименным союзным словом.  
А в целом, мне Ваш вопрос не очень понятен. Виктор1799 совершенно верно сформулировал признаки союзного слова, но об этом ли Вы спрашивали? Как-то нимвно думать, что кто-то не может отличить союзнок слово "которые" от союза "чтобы".   
Вот посложнее будет разобраться со словом "который", оно может быть и местоимением (местоименным прилагательным) и союзным словом. Сравните: "Который час?"

Answer (score 3):

В школе **союзным словом** называют **относительные местоимения и местоименные наречия**, которые служат для присоединения придаточного к главному в СПП. Чтобы выполнять задание В2 (части речи), хорошо бы выучить список подчинительных и сочинительных союзов, список местоимений с разрядами. Ведь только 3 слова: что, как , когда - могут быть как союзом, так и союзным словом. (Что - местоимение, как, когда- наречие).

Чтобы отличить союз от союзного слова, можно использовать несколько приемов, лучше в совокупности. В принципе есть один "пунктик", помогающий быстро понять, где союз, а где - самостоятельная часть речи. **На подчинительный союз НЕ падает логическое ударение.** Логическое ударение падает только на союзное слово. Одно "НО" - плохо читающие дети не умеют правильно понять и прочитать фразу, не понимают, куда же они поставили ударение, даже если сделали это правильно.

Другой способ: подумайте, не заменяет ли анализируемое слово другое слово из главной части? Например, в Вашем предложении слово "который" по смыслу заменяет слово "звездами".

Еще один прием: часто союз можно опустить. Сравним: Я знаю, что ты придешь. - Я знаю: ты придешь. (Что - союз)
Я знаю, что сказать  - опустить нельзя. На слово "Что" падает логическое ударение. По смыслу местоимение "Что" заменяет "слова" - Я знаю слова (которые скажу). Повторюсь - лучше использовать признаки в совокупности. И не поленитесь вызубрить сочинительные - подчинительные союзы. Очень поможет в определении типа сложного предложения. (отдельная тема со своими типичными ошибками на ЕГЭ, спрашивайте, если нужно).

Про предлог важно понимать. что он соединяет не просто слова, а именно существительные или местоимения с другими словами в предложении. **Предлог образует падежную форму.**  Это важно понимать. чтобы отличить производные предлог от, например, наречия. : **Гулял вокруг дома** (слово вокруг связывает существительное дом с глаголом гулял, могу заменить другим предлогом: гулял у (около, возле) дома. вокруг - предлог). Гулял вокруг. (Вокруг - наречие).

Answer (score 0):

Местоимение , связывающее части предложения , называется союзным словом.